# What is the best way to query on a foreign key column?

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I'm using JPA and Querydsl to dynamically build queries based on criteria that are being passed in through a REST API. For the most part, that's working fine but I'm unsure as to what is the best way to query for entities based on a value in a foreign key column.

To illustrate the scenario, consider the following (simplified) entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "division")
public class Division {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String uniqueKey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "division")
    private List<DivisionGroup> groups;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "division_group")
public class DivisionGroup {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "uniqueKey")
    private Division division;
}
```

Note, that Division is not referenced by `id` but by `uniqueKey` instead. Let's just say I have my reasons for doing this.

Now, I would like to run a query such as the following:

```
select * from division_group where division = 'someUniqueKey'
```

Seems simple enough but using JPA it requires a join and knowledge of which field contains the foreign key value (`uniqueKey` in this case). I imagine a JPA query would look similar to approach 1.

Note, that I'm not using any generated Q-types because the types are determined dynamically based on the request.

**Approach 1 - JPAQuery**

```
String divisionKey = "abc"; // the division's uniqueKey value from the request

// entity classes would be determined dynamically; hardcoded for this example
PathBuilder division = new PathBuilder<>(Division.class, "division");
PathBuilder divisionGroup = new PathBuilder<>(DivisionGroup.class, "divisionGroup");

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager)
    .from(divisionGroup)
    .innerJoin(divisionGroup.get("division"), division)
    .where(division.get("uniqueKey").eq(divisionKey))
    .list(divisionGroup);
```

I have the following problems with this approach:

- The join seems unnecessary (but I could live with that)
- It requires me to have knowledge of the fact that the `uniqueKey` field is used as join column. This is the real problem since the code should be able to handle all kinds of entities with various mappings.
- I'm somehow getting a `null=null` criteria mixed into the query. I'm guessing that might be unrelated though.

Alternatively, I looked into using `JPASQLQuery` instead of `JPAQuery`. That looks similar to the following:

**Approach 2 - JPASQLQuery**

```
String divisionKey = "abc"; // the division's uniqueKey value from the request

MySQLTemplates templates = new MySQLTemplates();
JPASQLQuery jpasqlQuery = new JPASQLQuery(entityManager, templates);

CustomHibernateNamingStrategy namingStrategy = new CustomHibernateNamingStrategy();
Class entityClass = DivisionGroup.class; // hardcoded for example
String tableName;

if (entityClass.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)) {
    tableName = namingStrategy.tableName(((Table) entityClass.getAnnotation(Table.class)).name());
} else {
    tableName = namingStrategy.classToTableName(entityClass.getSimpleName());
}

PathBuilder qDivisionGroup = new PathBuilder(entityClass, tableName);
Path sDivisionGroup = new PathImpl(entityClass, tableName);

List<DivisionGroup> groups = jpasqlQuery.from(sDivisionGroup)
    .where(Expressions.stringPath("division").eq(divisionKey))
    .list(qDivisionGroup);
```

This approach works and doesn't require any knowledge about how the `Division` entity looks like and that the `uniqueKey` field is used for the FK relationship. What I don't like about this approach:

- I have to figure out the table name. Would be nice if that could be done implicitly somehow since I'm using a JPA entity anyway.
- I have to provide `MySQLTemplates` which makes it harder to switch datasources.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

For the inverse fields of the association mapping, ID dereference can be used. For example `divisionGroup.division.id = 1` is valid JPQL/HQL, and won't require the join you describe. In QueryDSL this will be `divisionGroup.get("division").get("id").eq(1)` for example. This is possible even if the association is mapped by a foreign key (i.e. not the primary key). With your mapping `divisionGroup.get("division").get("uniqueKey")` should actually generate valid JPQL. Mind that Hibernate only recently started to support ID dereference for natural ID's (I've contributed it myself), so in older versions of Hibernate you'll still see the join being generated in the produced SQL query.